# Single row from a nested join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the following query :

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(purchase.entry.code,'') || coalesce(purchase.linentry.linecod,'') AS pkey,
    purchase.entry.code,
    purchase.linetry.linecod,
    purchase.entry.date,
    purchase.invoice.ninvoice,
    purchase.invoice.dateinvoice,
    gen.provider.code AS code1,
    gen.provider.name,
    gen.provider.name2,
    gen.provider.vatno,
    purchase.vlstinvoice.total,
    purchase.vlstinvoice.vat,
    purchase.vlstinvoice.totalVat
FROM
    purchase.entry  
JOIN
    purchase.linentry ON purchase.linentry.codentry = purchase.entry.code  
JOIN
    purchase.lininvoice ON purchase.lininvoice.codlinentry = purchase.linentry.code  
JOIN
    purchase.invoice ON purchase.invoice.code = purchase.lininvoice.codinvoice  
JOIN
    gen.provider ON gen.provider.code = purchase.entry.codprovider  
JOIN 
    purchase.vlstinvoice ON purchase.vlstinvoice.ninvoice = purchase.invoice.ninvoice
```

The query result gives me duplicated entry.code items. I need the unique entry.code in every row with the first or last linentry.linecod (since every entry.code can have multiple linentry.linecode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `distinct on`.  The following gets the first `linecod`:

```
select distinct on (purchase.entry.code)
       . . .  -- rest of columns
from . . .
order by purchase.entry.code, purchase.linentry.linecod;
```

Comment: My bad, i was using it different. I think this is the solution.